# For the creation of a prepopulate link, how can i strip out slashes if they occur in the title?

Tags: 7, theming

```
if(isset($node->field_eventform['und'][0]['nid'])) {
          echo '<div class="field field-name-field-eventform field-type-node-reference field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">';
          echo '<a href="/node/'.$node->field_eventform['und'][0]['nid'].'/'.$node->title.'/'.$node->nid.'">'.$node->field_eventform['und'][0]['node']->title.'</a>';
        echo '</div></div></div>';
   }

?>
```

With this snippet we prepopulate a webform for events. But when a site editor uses a "/" in the title the link doesn't work anymore. How can I strip out slashes if they occur in the title?

Comment: have you tried pathauto module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="/node/'.$node->field_eventform['und'][0]['nid'].'/'.str_replace('/','',$node->title).'/'.$node->nid.'">'.str_replace('/','',$node->field_eventform['und'][0]['node']->title).'</a>';
```

You have to check, if the link works, when you strip the '/', if not, replace the '' in str_replace with the correct replacement, that your path alias use.